# Windows 2008 R2 IIS FTP 7.5: Explicitly allow file access

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008-r2, ftp

I'm using IIS7 with FTP 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 and wondering if I could explicitly allow access to some files (for example only file X in dirA and *.txt in dirB) and deny read,write,list etc. on all others. As far as I have seen I could only allow or deny file extensions for the whole site and hide segments.
I already looked at custom feature providers but have not found a possibility/API for controlling file access.

Do somebody know how this could work or know a workaround for this?

Currently I'm using `proftpd` with Cygwin but this solution is far from optimal because the software is quite old (and insecure) and I often get `insufficent memory` or `file locked` error messages if I try to download files with >60kb or try to list a directory with more than ~700 files inside. This seems to be a known problem with `proftpd` and Windows Server 2008 R2 because of research that I found.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get proftpd compiled from source on Windows with cygwin. With the current version the problem described above is solved. The current cygwin proftpd binary package still have this issue.

There were some hassles around compiling proftpd on windows because of a bug (http://bugs.proftpd.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3972). This bug should be fixed on current versions and therefor it should be possible to compile as usual.